# What is the correct way to layout multiple buttons in Win32 Api?

Tags: c++, android-layout, winapi

I have a really simple question, but I'm not sure what the correct way is to approach it.

I'm working on a Win32 API application (in C++) and I'd like to put buttons right beside each other, just like this example in PhotoShop:

[image: Example of button layout]

My first idea is to parent all buttons in a container and then calculate the offset based on the size of the buttons. This seems simple, but I'm not sure if it's the way *normal* people do it.

My second idea is just a concept. Since I'm used to Android programming, I was hoping that there were pre-built layout methods, such as constraint layouts or frame layouts. I've done research, but haven't seen this, so I guess it's not possible, correct?

Comment: "*I'm not sure if it's the way normal people do it*" - normal people use higher level UI frameworks that can handle this for them. They don't resort to direct Win32 API calls to manage the UI.

Comment: Ohhh ok... Thanks for the heads up...

Comment: The Win32 API does not provide layout capabilities other than for dialogs, so you pretty much have to place your controls "by hand" at runtime.

Comment: I was just saved alot of time. Many thanks.

Comment: There is no *normal* when developing UI screens.  Usual American experience is to look at the middle of the screen or the top left corner; so maybe you might want to place your buttons there.  However, a common division is to have buttons on the left column; but then some web sites have the buttons horizontally below the company's logo.  You could develop some "strawman" examples and take surveys...

Comment: *"I was hoping that there were pre-built layout methods, such as constraint layouts or frame layouts"* - There is, but not with the classic common controls. [WinUI](https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/), on the other hand, allows you to define your UI in markup.